# How to scrape a part of a google search result

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I want to scrape the information from AMD stock that google provide. 
I have been able to scrape the whole webpage, but as soon I try to get a specific *div* or *class* I am not able to find anything and the console returns []. 
When scraping the whole page I cannot find those classes either, after searching I found that this is possibly hidden by Javascript and can somehow be accesed with Selenium? I tried to use Selenium Webdriver but this got me nowhere.

This is what i have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
from selenium import webdriver

requests.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"}


url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=amd+stock&oq=amd+stock&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l5j69i60.1017j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
source_code = requests.get(url, requests.headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, "html.parser")
amd = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'aviV4d'})
print(amd)
```

When printing 'soup' I get the whole page, but when printing 'amd' I get [].

Comment: _I found that this is possibly hidden by JavaScript...._ Not hidden, just dynamically generated using JavaScript. Selenium replaces requests and BeautifulSoup, so there’s not much that can currently be done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, but use `headers=` parameter in `request()` call:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=amd+stock&oq=amd+stock&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l5j69i60.1017j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
source_code = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, "html.parser")
amd = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'aviV4d'})
print(amd.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[:3])
```

Prints:

```
['Advanced Micro Devices', 'NASDAQ: AMD', '48,16']
```

Comment: That seemed to work! Is it also possible to get an output that allows me to scrape the whole graph, layout, etc...? So that I can use it on a website.

Comment: Alright well the fact that this solution works invalidates most of the current question, no?

Comment: So that would be a new question to post on stack overflow you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add amd.response or amd.text

```py
print(amd.response)
print(amd.text)
```

Comment: Even if OP’s issue weren’t related to JavaScript, like an incorrect BeautifulSoup query, this still wouldn’t solve anything. In fact, I believe it will always throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

That's a dynamic page, it's not gonna give the stock price by just requesting the page source via `requests`. You will have to use scraping to do that. Try this instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
chromedriver_path = './chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=amd+stock&oq=amd+stock&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l5j69i60.1017j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")

time.sleep(2)
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="knowledge-finance-wholepage__entity-summary"]/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]')

print(x.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
48.16
```

Comment: _You will have to use scraping to do that._ They already are doing web scraping though.